# Can you pass an external function to a Vue component as a prop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a legacy codebase mostly built in PHP. I'm researching how to turn commonly used parts of the code into re-usable Vue components that can be plugged in as needed.

In one case, I have an onclick event in the html which will need to be individually passed to a child component. `onclick="func()"`

I want to be able to pass that func to the component from the markup, without defining this one-time use function as a property method either on the component or its parents.

I can't find anything in the Vue docs or elsewhere on how to do that. Every attempt I make gives an error:

> Property or method "hi" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

Is there a way to pass externally-defined functions in the global scope to a Vue instance?

Vue tabs:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = true;


Vue.component('tabs', {
  template: `
    <div class="qv-tabs">
      <div class="tab">
        <ul>
          <li v-for="tab in tabs"
              :class="{'is-active' : tab.isActive}"
              @click="tab.callHandler"
          > 
            <a :href="tab.href" @click="selectTab(tab)">{{tab.name}}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <slot></slot>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  data(){
    return{
      tabs: []
    };
  },
  created(){
    this.tabs = this.$children;
  },
  methods:{
    selectTab(selectedTab){
      this.tabs.forEach(tab => {
        tab.isActive = (tab.name == selectedTab.name);
      });
    },
    otherHi() {
      alert('other hi');
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('tab', {
  template: `
    <div v-show="isActive">
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
  `,
  props: {
    name: {required: true},
    selected: {default: false},
    callHandler: Function,
    clickHandler: {
      type: Function,
      default: function() { console.log('default click handler') }
    }
  },
  data(){
    return{
      isActive: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    callHandler() {
      console.log('call handler called');
      this.clickHandler();
    }
  },
  computed:{
    href(){
      return '#' + this.name.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-');
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.isActive = this.selected;
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '.app',
  methods: {
    vueHi() { alert('hi from vue'); }
  }
});

function hi() {
  alert('hi!');
}
```

Markup:

```html
<div class="app">
    <tabs>
      <tab name="Tab 1" :selected="true" v-bind:call-handler="hi">
        <p>Tab content</p>
      </tab>
      <tab name="Tab 2">
        <p>Different content for Tab 2</p>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </div>
```

Comment: I've never seen a good example of needing a functional prop. Could you use an event instead, ie your component emits an event and the parent handles that?

Comment: That seems to be the primary suggestion from the docs, and it makes the problem worse. Now instead of having the component that can handle its own single-use click event, I have every instance of its parent component having a function that's never used by the component itself, and only once in the whole code base used by a child element. That still seems like the wrong way to structure this.

Fundamentally, I don't need to pass a functional prop, I need to allow a component to reference an externally-defined function either without using the method object, or by using it as a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You could define your methods like this in your component :

```
...
methods: {
   hi
}
...
```

But you will have to define it in every component where you need this function. Maybe you can use a mixin that define the methods you want to access from yours components, and use this mixins in these components ? https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html

Anoter solution ( depending on what you try to achieve ) is to add your method to the Vue prototype like explained here :
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html

```
Vue.prototype.$reverseText = function(string) {
  return string.split('')
    .reverse()
    .join('')
}
```

With this method defined in the Vue prototype, you can use the reverseText method like this in all of your components template :

```
...
<div> {{ $reverseText('hello') }} </div>
...
```

Or from yours script with `this` :

```
methods: {
  sayReverseHello() {
    this.$reverseText('hello')
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't think this helps for the reason you mentioned - I am trying to avoid having a single-use event function defined on every component.
The way I envision this, the component should only define the methods and properties that will be used by every instance, but should be able to accept outside functions for usage with specific instances.

Comment: So maybe the solution that involve adding the method you need in the prototype is the one that suits the most to your needs ? 
Unfortanely for you, there is no others way to use an external javascript function directly in your template without wrapping it like mentionned above.